# Anylogic: reading excel cells value for dynamic parameters definition

Tags: java, anylogic, flexibility

Cheers Everyone,
here is my problem.
I'm creating an Anylogic model trying to make it as flexible as possible. This means that I'm feeding some time values directly from an Excel spreadsheet.
In order to create a delay loop that changes its value every time by going row by row, I created a parameter and a variable that work like this:

row_index (variable) with initial value 4
parameter with default value - excel_spreadsheet.getCellNumericValue("Sp_A", row_index, 6)

But as soon as I run my simulation this happens:
The row #0 (1-based) does not exist

My goal is to update the row_index every time that my delay is over and so on.
I tried to update the parameter value (starting from zero) after starting the simulation (for example on the on enter of a queue) but I got another error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you all in advance,
Ale

Comment: So is the initial value of row_index 4 or 0?

Comment: "The row #0 (1-based) does not exist" --> looks like you try to load row zero but should start with row 1, no?

Comment: @mczandrea the initial value is 4

Comment: @Benjamin i'm not trying to load row 0. The initial value for the variable is 4

Comment: share some more details, screenshots, etc. Ideally, simplify the root problem for us as well :). Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions

1. Instead of writing the code directly to the 'Default value' of your parameter, set it to an arbitrary number and set the value somewhere else. For example write `myParameter = excel_spreadsheet.getCellNumericValue(1, row_index, 6);` in the 'On startup:' action of the agent.
2. Use a Variable instead of a Parameter (if you don't need the special capabilities of parameters).

EDIT: This only solves the error on startup. You need to manually update the parameter/variable value too when the row_index is changed

Comment: solved with method 1 but calling. Not directly on the sturtup but the in the enter object before the delay. Thank you a lot!